# OnScrollListener not working when used via databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to use onScrollListener to hide BottomNavigationView and other UI elements of mainActivity. while my recyclerview is located in the fragment inside the mainActivity and I am using custom binding adapter to inflate the recyclerview. I am currently using databinding.

My code

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding= FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        hideFloatingActionButton()

        binding.dataList = DataProvider.productList

        return binding.root

    }

    private fun hideFloatingActionButton(){

        rv_products?.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if (dy > 0) {
                    // Scrolling up
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Going upp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

//                    if (fab_button.visibility==View.INVISIBLE){
//                        fab_button.visibility=View.VISIBLE
//                    }

                    if (bottomNav.visibility==View.INVISIBLE){
                        bottomNav.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                    }


                } else {
                    // Scrolling down
//                    if (fab_button.visibility==View.VISIBLE){
//                        fab_button.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
//                    }
                }

                if (bottomNav.visibility==View.VISIBLE){
                    bottomNav.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }

            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Going upp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                } else if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    // Do something
                } else {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        })


    }



}
```

recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `recyclerView` from `data binding`  object, then use `addOnScrollListener`. Declare an instance variable `private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding` and initialize it inside `onCreateView()` `binding= FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)`.

Now get `recyclerView` inside `hideFloatingActionButton()` method like `binding.rvProducts.addOnScrollListener(your callback)`